# Subscribers currently in a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, automationstudio, contactbuilder

What ways could you create a data extension that contains all the subscribers (SubscriberKeys) that are currently “in” a Journey (Journey Builder)?

The Journey I would like to do this for is a complex activity with multiple decision branches resulting in multiple possible journey durations. For example; if the customer didn’t open Email1 after 2 days, then send Email2; else Exit Journey. If the customer didn’t open Email2 after 2 days, then send Email3; else Exit Journey. Wait 2 more days, then End Journey.
The minimum journey duration for the above example is 2 days, while the maximum is 6 days.

Note that I don’t want a list of subscribers that “entered” a Journey, but a list of the ones that are “currently in” a Journey and have not yet exited. Answer must account for non-standard Journey exits including Unsubscribes/Contact Deletes, etc.

Comment: Does this help? https://gortonington.com/journey-history-for-last-30-days-via-api/

Comment: Maybe i am just dull but you can just do that with engagement splits inside a journey and select opens or clicks or whatever... then wait 2 days and send the next email. Where is the need for the dataextension?

Comment: Thanks Zuzannamj, however I’m look for a “currently in journey”, not a log of events after a subscriber has complete each journey activity - since it’s possible for a subscriber to complete an activity in the journey, and then be deleted/unsubscribed/etc shortly after; which will not show up in that API (to my understanding).

Comment: Hi Johannes, I’m looking for a DE of subscribers in a complex journey where the “journey duration” is not fixed. I used the engagement split example above to exemplify how this “unknown journey duration” could operate in a complex, multi-decision branching journey.

Answer (score 11):

**Update May 2021:**

Due to recent changes in the internal table structure of Marketing Cloud Journey Builder, it is no longer possible to request this custom data view. I will provide an update as soon as there is a way of gaining insights into Contact journey presence.

**END of update**

My best advice is to ask Salesforce for a custom data view. This is something that can easily be done, however it will have a cost, as it is a custom development. However, it will let you achieve exactly what you are after.
Here is some sample data from such a custom data view, fetched in Query Studio:
[image]

```
select JourneyVersionNumber
      ,JourneyName
      ,JourneyStatus
      ,ContactKey
      ,ContactID
      ,ContactStatus
      ,EntryDate
      ,ExitDate
from _ContactJourneyPresence
```

You can also use a WHERE clause, showing only those contacts who currently are a part of a journey:

```
select JourneyVersionNumber
      ,JourneyName
      ,JourneyStatus
      ,ContactKey
      ,ContactID
      ,ContactStatus
      ,EntryDate
      ,ExitDate
from _ContactJourneyPresence
where ContactStatus
= 'Active'
```

Here you will see all these records have an empty ExitDate, meaning they still are part of a journey:

[image]

Given that such a task is custom development, it is more or less up to you to define which fields you need to have as part of such a data view, as long as the information is available within the platform.

Any "exit" (regular exit, exit criteria, goal criteria) will be reflected in ExitDate. It is afaik also possible to provide the type of exit, kicking the contact out of the journey, as a separate column.

Comment: How on bloody earth shall a customer know that salesforce can provide something like that. It is just really stupid that they do not share this info. Atleast i did not know that they offer these services. Great advice though ;) Can you give an estimate of the cost? Again your answer "competes" against Jonas :D

Comment: I admit, Googling "Custom Data View" does not return a lot results :-)

Comment: Custom Data Views, who would have thought :-) And yes please do tell how much something like this could cost?

Comment: @zuzannamj I'm an architect, not a salesman ;-)

Comment: Do you know if that ExitDate field is populated through Exit Criteria/Goals as well?

Comment: @AnonWonderer - yes, see my updated answer

Comment: @Lukas Any chance you/Salesforce can teach us what is possible from salesforce as an "archietect" when you know the "behind the scenes" database? I believe many people like zuzanna and me are really interested in that stuff. Couldn't you see that as investment into the platform (and people)? Any chance Salesforce could deliver a "deeper" training to somewhat talented or helping people on this platform? btw great diplomatic answer on the cost-estimate lukas -.- :D

Comment: My recommendation I give every client and user I run into is if you have an idea on something but can't think of a good way to do it with the current toolset then put in a case in support or reach out to your account rep. Worst they can say is that it is not possible, but a lot of time (for a price) they can give you an option.

Comment: @Gortonington I've kind of lost hope on the support. A lot of times, they give random answers that I had to challenge to get a real answer..

Comment: @RachidMamai - I know they can be difficult at times, but sometimes there is no alternative. I would definitely recommend going to account/sales rep first for feature requests as they will move it in the right way and skip a bit of headache. But sometimes you just gotta go to support and bring the torches and pitchforks until you get to the right tier to provide you the info you need. To be fair, a lot of these questions are above their expected knowledge base and likely should be escalated right away, but that isn't always how it works and that can create difficulty and frustration.

Comment: Agree with @Gortonington - keep pushing those requests, as without communication/feedback from clients and partners, Salesforce cannot improve. Either you will be provided a "hidden" solution, using e.g. business rules or custom data views, or a Voice of Customer will be created. Even logging cases on specific topics, without a solution, helps prioritise the development track of engineering teams.

Comment: I've asked Salesforce for Service Engagement Costs to have this Customer Data View created. Typical custom reports/requests were quoted as ~$10,000 USD and make take 1-3 months to complete; however the exact time and cost of this request has not been provided. I'll update this ticket as I find out more. An answer to this question may not be as straightforward as I had hoped!

Comment: @CameronRobert Complexity here should be well below a custom report. Delivery time depends on the availability of a data architect. Once built, deploying it should not take more than few days.

Comment: @CameronRobert - out of curiosity, did you manage to move forward with the custom data view approach?

Comment: @LukasLunow I’ve asked for a scope/cost so it can be added to your answer; so that future answer-seekers aren’t left with a dead end. The cost/benefit with be dependant on each use case. Stay tuned!

Comment: @CameronRobert Is there any info on the costs you can provide? Would be nice to make the "dead end" an open gate ;)

Comment: Sadly not sorry @JohannesSchapdick - Salesforce was not able to answer my costing question before "2020 world events" intervened. For now I'm building journeys using tracking method built in to detect where they are in the Journey.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a usecase for a journey tracking data extension:

Sendable DE:
SubscriberKey, Status, Timestamp

On entering the journey use an update contact event to track a field "status" with value "entered" and set timestamp to "current date". You do not need to fill anything into the SubscriberKey field, this is populated automatically if it has that name.

On all exits, track the value "exit" in the same DE.

Then, build an SQL query that filters down all records in the tracking DE that do NOT have status "exit". 
Join this with your All Subscribers List, or wherever you track unsubscriptions to account for those.
Since the tracking DE MUST be sendable anyway to use Update Contact, contact deletion will affect records in that DE and they won't be listed.

Limitation: Exit tracking doesn't work with Goal-based-exits or Exit criteria. These cannot really be tracked, so my suggestion is, refrain from using those.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, this is my current solution that I’ve been using since Journey Builder was released. I can confirm it works, however with limitations such as timing (how often you refresh the SQL) and goal based exits - as you mentioned. I’m glad that others have defaulted to this method of subscriber tracking!

Comment: We do something similar to this, except we have a sweeper that sweeps updates to a log with a proper primary key, since update contact doesn't respect PKs.

Comment: Just do understand it correctly: You use the updatecontact activity like jonas said and you defined another dataextension with properly configured contraints like primary keys and then you use a sql query or something like this to get it to the log dataextension? Whats your schedule on the sweeper and what actually is your sweeper? Actually the schedule would be the most interesting part i guess.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick - If you want more info on Adam's solution, he posted a blog post on this - https://sprignaturemoves.com/journey-logging-using-update-contact/

Comment: This was a good read. We do something similar. It hasn't been mentioned so worth pointing out that to get around the exist criteria issue, you can instead put your exit criteria in decision splits and then have your Update Contact activity down that path to mark people as exited. It can make the canvas a bit messier but at least you get 100% coverage. One caveat: won't work with Goals :(