# How to query only subscribers that are in an active journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

We want to get only subscribers that are on an active journey using SQL.
Is that possible using data views, and **without** updating another status DE in every journey?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such data view, but are your contacts in a wait step and have they been sent an email in the journey? Then you can know, which subscribers entered that journey.

Comment: Yes it is possible, i am searching a post from lukas lunow right now as soon as i found it i post it here.

Comment: @SwatiMishra, we want all contacts, not related to the step they are on the journey.

Comment: It is not easily possible. You might need a custom data view, as described here: [Subscribers currently in a Journey](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293381/subscribers-currently-in-a-journey) - was it this post you were looking for, @JohannesSchapdick? :-)

Comment: Of course i was searching for exactly that post... i always search for Journey Activity SQL and so on... but this way i never got the result :D

Comment: @LukasLunow, yes, it does looks not simple at all. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @yoni349 - requesting a custom data view is actually quite simple, but will cost you.