# Trying to find out WHO is in each step of a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm trying to find out if there is any way to determine who is in each step of a journey.  I'm aware that there are a couple of data views that exist for journeys, namely _Journey and _JourneyActivity.  My ask is that I find out who exactly is in the circled step below in the screenshot.  I'm not too sure how to do this, if it's even possible.  Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to know who reached this particular step of your journey, you could implement an Update Contact block which allows you to log information to a data extension. This way you would obtain information who landed on the path right before the split from your screen.

The are some limitations though:

- you can only log 5 values this way
- the data extension used as a log needs to be sendable
- by default the values put into the data extension are hard-coded and you need a workaround to get dynamic values that are different for each customer - you can find it [here in the answer of @jogsottot](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/247678/39888) (basically pretend you want to configure a SF object and just copy the string containing Journey Data into the Update Contact activity)

This will create a log which will log all entries on that path and you could set some retention settings to limit who will be displayed there.

Answer (score 1):

This number indicates how many have been **through** this particular step, as the only step you can be **in** is a wait step. It is not possible to use any of the available data views or reports to identify which step a given contact has reached.

There is an option to ask Salesforce for a custom data view, as in my [example here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/293395). There might be a possibility of a more sophisticated solution, but I am yet to see it built.

One can ask, what would a purpose of such a solution be, and if it could be achieved through different means.